# soccer bet possibilities

Tags: javascript

I want to show every possible way a game could end.

I've got a form where the user can add every soccer match.

Now I want to show in a table all the possible ways the matches could end.

e.g:

- team1 vs. team2,
- team3 vs team4

Table (Win / Lose / Draw) should be something like:

- team1, team3
- team1, team4
- team1, team3 team4 draw
- team2, team3
- team2, team4
- team2, team3 team4 draw
- team3, team1 team2 draw
- team4, team1 team2 draw
- team1 team2 draw, team3 team4 draw

Comment: I assume you just mean  Win / Loose / Draw?

Comment: yes  right, and it could also be only one match or also 5 matches

Comment: Just a bit more clarification, are you wanting every possibility of each team playing each other.  As working out all possibilities of every soccer match, is just every soccer match * 3 (win/loose/draw)..

Comment: i want the possibility of each match combined with the others. So i've got 3^n possibilities (n = number of games)

Comment: I think your confusing things here by saying `match`, a match is already made up of two teams..  So IOW: you want all possibility's of each team playing each team.  And are you wanting like @Emil S. Jørgensen said a tournament, or is it a league..?, with a league its also possible for 2 teams to play again, as we have Home & Away matches, so the only duplicate you would have to check for, is playing yourself.

Comment: no they only play once

Answer (score 0):

The example below tries every unique combination of teams and lists an outcome for each possible outcome.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics

```js
var teams = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var fallouts = ["win", "lose", "draw"];
for (var ti1 = 0; ti1 < teams.length; ti1++) {
  var t1 = teams[ti1];
  for (var ti2 = ti1 + 1; ti2 < teams.length; ti2++) {
    if (ti1 == ti2) {
      continue;
    }
    var t2 = teams[ti2];
    for (var f = 0; f < fallouts.length; f++) {
      var fallout = fallouts[f];
      document.write("Team " + t1 + " matches against team " + t2 + " for a " + fallout + "<br/>")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thats not yet what i want, this snipped alwas combines 2 games with each other, but i want the possibility of each match combined with all the others. So i've got 3^n possibilities (n = number of games)

Comment: So you don't want the possible outcomes of each match, but the possible outcome of each step in a tournament?

Comment: @user3530080  Are you sure its 3^n, as even 10 teams it's going to be 59,049 possibility's.. :)

Comment: yes its 3^n . i want the oucomes of each match combined with the outcomes of the others

Comment: You want to show `Math.pow(3,10)` potential outcomes? What would your users even do with that much information?

Comment: i want to connect it also with bet quotes and want to show them then the multiplicated quote and the different possibilities, the users have to bet

Comment: This is possible by modifying my snippet above, but to get it right requires a lot of guesswork or back-and-fourth to do so this is as far as i will go for now. If and When you have some actual code to review, then you can come back.